# mv: rename <oldname> to <newname>/<oldname>: Invalid argument

Tags: shell, zsh, freebsd, mv

On my TrueNAS (FreeBSD 13.1) server I have a directory named `OldHDD` which I want to rename, but I get an error:

```bash
% mv OldHDD oldhdd
mv: rename OldHDD to oldhdd/OldHDD: Invalid argument
```

I have tried different variations of the command, but none worked:

```bash
% mv ./OldHDD oldhdd
mv: rename ./OldHDD to oldhdd/OldHDD: Invalid argument

% mv -- OldHDD oldhdd
mv: rename OldHDD to oldhdd/OldHDD: Invalid argument

% mv /full/path/to//OldHDD /full/path/to/oldhdd
mv: rename /full/path/to/OldHDD to /full/path/to/oldhdd/OldHDD: Invalid argument
```

I have also tried using `mmv`, and even though it doesn't report errors, the name of directory doesn't change:

```bash
% ls
total 1
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  group     3B Apr 10 21:50 OldHDD

% mmv -rv OldHDD oldhdd
OldHDD -> oldhdd : done

% ls
total 1
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  group     3B Apr 10 21:50 OldHDD
```

I thought that maybe an issue is somehow with contents of the directory,  but I can rename sub-directories it contains just fine.

I tried copying the directory to check if metadata causes problems, but the same problem persists with the copied directory.

The only time when I managed to rename this directory was when I: (1) created (by mistake) partial copy of `OldHDD` with only one sub-directory, and (2) created tar archive of the sub-drector inside `OldHDD`. But I am hesitant to create tar archive of the original directory, due to its size.

Can someone explain how can I rename this directory and what is happening here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The filesystem on your NAS is case-insensitive¹, so `OldHDD` and `oldhdd` are the same file. But your operating system is case-sensitive, so it considers those different names. The `mv` command asks the filesystem whether the destination `oldhdd` is an existing directory, and the answer is yes, since this is just some case variation on `OldHDD`. Therefore `mv` attempts to move the source into this existing directory. But the source is the same directory, so this is an attempt to make a directory a subdirectory of itself, which the filesystem rejects.

To rename a file in a way that only changes the case on a case-insensitive filesystem, rename it twice, using an intermediate name that is not a case variation.

```
mv OldHDD oldhdd.temp_name
mv oldhdd.temp_name oldhdd
```

¹  <sub>But it's case-preserving: it remembers the case on the names it stores. `OldHDD` and `oldhdd` are different ways to spell the same file name, but the filesystem remembers which spelling is the desired one.</sub>